# "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" when constructing JavaScript code with PHP from generic file

Tags: javascript, php, generics, web

I'm trying to use PHP to generate a JavaScript switch block by taking input from TemplateList.txt. It works fine when I only have one line in TemplateList.txt, but when I have two or more I get an error in the console saying I have a

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

on the line of the php opening  tag, I can't see any unclosed strings.

```
<?php 
$listHandle = fopen('templates/TemplateList.txt', 'r');

while (!feof($listHandle)) {                    
   $thisTemplate = fgets($listHandle);   
   echo "case \"" . $thisTemplate . "\": " . $thisTemplate . "();  break; "; 
}  

fclose($listHandle);
?>
```

My TemplateList.txt file looks like this:

```
heart_by_john
dog_by_sue
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not looking at the JavaScript you are generating so you can determine what the syntax error actually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgets()` function includes the line break in the returned string, so you add a line break to your JS inside the string. Replace

```
$thisTemplate = fgets($listHandle);
```

by

```
$thisTemplate = trim(fgets($listHandle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi that's because there is a line break after each word in your list

This code works for me.

```
$path = 'templates/TemplateList.txt';

$str = '';
if(file_exists($path)){         
    $listHandle = file($path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($listHandle as $line_num => $line){                   
        $str .= "case \"" . $line . "\": " . $line . "();  break; "; 
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: I tried copying your exact code and replacing my entire php block with it. Same result, except this: the error is now on the line ______

          foreach ($listHandle as $line_num => $line){